# ~/.local/share/ is not in $XDG_DATA_DIRS, however .desktop files under the applications folder is shown in GNOME launcher

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment, freedesktop

I'm using GNOME under Arch Linux.
According to [freedesktop Menu Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html#paths), `.desktop` files are under `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/`.
But when I was cleaning desktop entries today, I noticed that there's no `/home/<my usr name>/.local/share/` in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`, but `.desktop` files under `~/.local/share/applications/` are shown in GNOME Launcher.

Am I missing something important?